# Time complexity of python two-sum solution

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a question about the a widely accepted solution to the classic leetcode two-sum question, which reads as follows:

*Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.*

The solution I'm referring to iterates over `nums` and stores a mapping of values in `nums` to their indices. With each iteration over `nums`, we check if there is a complementary key to the current element in `nums` which would give us `target`, and if so we lookup and return its value:

```
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        lookup = {}
        for i in range(0, len(nums)): 
            if target - nums[i] in lookup:
                return [i, lookup[target - nums[i]]]
            lookup[nums[i]] = i
```

Everyone seems to think this is an O(n) solution. However, I understand it to be O(n^2). For each iteration `i`, we're also iterating over potentially `n-1` keys in the lookup table when we do `nums[i] in lookup`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The worst case for a dictionary lookup is O(n) key comparisons, but practically speaking it's O(1) comparisons. A lot of stuff gets swept under the rug when dealing with hashtable complexities in real programs!

Answer (score 0):

As `lookup` is a dictionary, it doesn't linearly search through its keys when looking up a value. It uses a mathematical function (called a hash) to calculate the value's location using the input key. This is an O(1) operation, meaning that checking if `nums[i] in lookup` is also an O(1) operation.

If `lookup` were a list, then you'd be right in saying the algorithm was O(n²)

You can google "Python how do dictionaries work" or something similar to find out more. I found [this](https://www.jessicayung.com/how-python-implements-dictionaries/) as the first result :)

Comment: This is practically speaking right, but theoretically wrong. Hashing isn't O(1) - it's at least linear in the size of the thing that's being hashed, which is relevant because if you have an input list of unique items the things must grow in size like Omega(log(n)) otherwise they can't all be different. Hashtable operations are amortized O(1) comparisons (which ignores the cost of hashing and the cost of each comparison, and allows for the possibility that some operations take much longer, eg when the hashtable needs to be resized).

Comment: thanks! I was going off what I read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complexity-cheat-sheet-for-python-operations/) which I guess might be incorrect? when I run tests with `timeit` it does seem that `d.get(k)` and `k in d` take the same amount of time.